# Changing the title, destroys linking from other questions?

Tags: discussion

If I change the title of a question, will I corrupt the links from other questions to that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in my experience.

I changed the title of a question a while ago and I had the same worries.

It seems that SE does create a new url including the new title, but keeps the old url too and just makes it point to the new one.

Comment: thanks martin ;)